# Facing issue in trasfering file on ftp mule

Tags: salesforce, mule, mule-studio

I am facing issue while transfering my file to ftp server.
following is my code

```
<sfdc:config name="Salesforce" username="myUserName" password="pwd" securityToken="mytokens" doc:name="Salesforce"/>
    <file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <data-mapper:config name="List_Contact__To_CSV" transformationGraphPath="list_contact__to_csv.grf" doc:name="List_Contact__To_CSV"/>
    <ftp:connector name="ftpConnector"   streaming="true" doc:name="FTP"/>
    <batch:job name="Batch1">
        <batch:threading-profile poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
        <batch:input>
            <poll doc:name="Poll">
                <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="2" timeUnit="MINUTES"/>
                <sfdc:query config-ref="Salesforce" query="dsql:SELECT Email,Name FROM Contact" fetchSize="20" doc:name="Salesforce"/>
            </poll>
        </batch:input>
        <batch:process-records>
            <batch:step name="Batch_Step">
                <batch:commit size="20" doc:name="Batch Commit">
                    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="List_Contact__To_CSV" doc:name="List&lt;Contact&gt; To CSV"/>
                    <file:outbound-endpoint path="/home/Desktop/Input" outputPattern="test.csv" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                    <ftp:outbound-endpoint path="myPath" host="208.115.etc.." port="21" user="name@client.test.in" password="pwd" outputPattern="test.csv" connector-ref="ftpConnector" mimeType="application/csv" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="ftp"/>
                </batch:commit>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:process-records>
    </batch:job>
```

my file is saved successfully on my desktop but didn't transfer on my ftp server. I got following error

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. hostname can't be null (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
  java.net.InetSocketAddress:149 (null)
2. hostname can't be null (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) (org.mule.transport.ConnectException)
  org.mule.transport.ftp.FtpConnector:552 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/ConnectException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname can't be null
```

What is the solution please help me

Answer (score 0):

Since your login credentials include @, you must escape it using %40.
Try changing your user to user="name%40client.test.in"